# Inspiron 15 7000 USB ports randomly disconnect

Tags: usb, power-management

Folks I have an issue where my keyboard or mice will loose connection with the laptop. Some considerations, I`ve disabled usb sleep mode and I play with the laptop lid closed. Using windows 10. If I disconnect and reconect the device it returns to function. Ideas?

Comment: Is there anything else running on the USB at the same time?

Comment: No, it happens both to keyboard and mice I've tried different ports both 2 and 3.0, with the laptop on the battery and power cord. Now I will try a externally powered hub.